# Does HBase and Hive need to be co-located on the same machine?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

We currently build a new hbase cluster. The architecture is as follow:

[image: hbase architecture]

now I want to add a new hive cluster. But I don't know if I should build hive on the same hadoop cluster with hbase. Or should I build a new hadoop cluster for hive?

If I build a new hadoop cluster for hive, will the traffic between hive and hbase be too huge when I execute SQL to aggregate data of hbase (AFAIK, hive need to import the data on hbase to its own hdfs storage)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets first define what is the traffic between HBase and Hive. In every Hive query you will either:

- use Hive for querying HBase directly
- use Hive to perform Join requests of Warehouse tables with HBase table
- use Hive to perform Join requests of external tables with HBase table

If you take a deep dive into the architecture of all these components you will notice that Hive Warehouse and Hbase both use HDFS behind the scene. Same can be considered to external tables which are located in HDFS. So if you deploy Hive into current architecture, there internal data would physically be stored at the same place as HBase - in the DataNodes of your data Rack. It means that you traffic would be optimal for the tasks which will be scheduled by YARN through your Hive queries. If you create another Rack for hive Warehouse with a set of separate DataNodes located at another Data Center, this would negatively impact your performance.

So if you have enough capacities to keep data within single Rack for all your services, go this way. You can read more about [Hive](https://oyermolenko.blog/2017/02/16/structuring-hadoop-data-through-hive-and-sql/) and [HBase](https://oyermolenko.blog/2017/02/21/hbase-as-primary-nosql-hadoop-storage/) infrastructure in referenced links.

Comment: Hi Alex. I've read the document https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration. And I know if I set up a hive cluster with hbase on the same datanodes, I can map an external table to an existing hbase table. So if I understand correctly, hive doesn't have to store a data copy for that hbase table as it can read it directly. And now the question is, will it be a huge impact to the performance of hbase, as the SQL may scan too many rows in hbase table, or  the SQL execution is a complex map-reduce task?

Comment: @Alexis This is actually how we are using it in our company. Hive will perform the role of translator of your SQL queries to HBase scanners, so technically there will be no differences if you will perform this step directly through HBase or by allowing Hive to do this. If you look into the HBaseStorageHandler class you will see that it uses standard HBase java client behind the scene